# Alternative way to store input data of a user

Tags: grails

I am currently working on a grails project. What I am trying to do now is to create an application that can store values of the user input without saving it on a database, and later access that stored values for further processes. Is there a way on how to realize this?

Please help. Thanks!

**Update:**

Sorry for the vague question..through further reading I have come to a solution that putting the user data input in a file is the solution to this query. It would be saved in a non-volatile storage, but not in the database perse..Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options are almost endless.
You could just keep the data in memory, if it doesn't need to survive a restart.
Otherwise, you could write it to file, etc.
But it all comes down to pretty much the same thing as using a database.
Just curious - why don't you want to use a database?

Comment: You dont want to keep it in volatile storage neither in database ! Thats strange. You can either keep in memory or keep in some type of persistent storage. There are endless options for both but ultimately you will have to keep it somewhere. You arent clear about what you want to achieve. Is it data security or database itself your issue ?